# Why are none of the $\overline{Y_i}$ contained in one another?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $X$ be a topological space which is a union of finitely many irreducible closed sets $X_1, ... , X_n$.

**Lemma:** if none of the $X_i$ are contained in one another, then $X_1, ... , X_n$ are the distinct irreducible components of $X$.

Now let $Y \subseteq X$ have finitely many irreducible components $Y_1, ... , Y_n$.  Then (what I want to prove is) $\overline{Y}$ has finitely many irreducible components $\overline{Y_1}, ... , \overline{Y_n}$; and they are distinct.

Since $\overline{Y}$ is the union of irreducible closed subsets $\overline{Y_1}, ... , \overline{Y_n}$, we can apply the lemma if we can show that none of the $\overline{Y_i}$ are contained in one another.  Why is this?

Comment: Suppose $Y \subseteq X$ is a subspace and $Z$ a set closed in $Y$. Then $\overline{Z} \cap Y = Z$.

Comment: I passed a topology qual yet somehow this eluded me.  Thanks